# find key value based on value field python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the values are lists. I would like to look for a specific value in the lists (value field of dictionary) and return the key value:

```
dict={'a':['ab','cd','ef'], 'b':['gh', 'ij'], 'c':['kl', 'mn']}
```

So for 'ef' I would get 'a', for 'mn' I would get 'c'...

I have tryied

```
value_key=[a for a,b in dict if value in b]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Dictionaries are only meant to go one way (from key to the value).  If you find yourself needing to go the other way around, they are not the correct structure to be using

Comment: Your dictionary is not valid.

Comment: Moreover, you cannot simply "reverse" your dictionary because lists cannot be keys

Comment: Use `dict.items()`, it returns both key and value.

Comment: Obligatory: Don't call your own variable `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to do indexing this way more than once, you should build the reverse mapping, from values (sub-values really) to keys:

```
{ vsub:k for k, v in d.iteritems() for vsub in v }
```

This takes your original dict (called `d` here because `dict` is a builtin name in Python), and "inverts" it, with the tweak of mapping each sub-value (the elements within the lists).

Once you have this new dict, you can simply index into it by keys like 'ab' to get 'a':

```
{'ab': 'a', 'ef': 'a', 'mn': 'c', 'kl': 'c', 'ij': 'b', 'cd': 'a', 'gh': 'b'}
```

Comment: (Note that this requires the sub-values to be unique. If they're not, you're pretty much stuck with the much less efficient lookups in the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the dictionary with `for key in dict_object`, and then use `in` operator to check if the value being searched is in the dictionary's value corresponding to the key. If it exists, then retain the key for the output.

```
my_dict,val={"a": ["ab", "cd", "ef"], "b": ["gh", "ij"], "c": ["kl", "mn"]}, "ef"
print [key for key in my_dict if val in my_dict[key]]
# ['a']
```

The advantage of this method is, it will work irrespective of the current popular Python versions, as we don't have to worry about `items` and `iteritems` methods.